# Yii - CHtml::ajaxLink - TypeError: settings is undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii

I am displaying a table generated from a model named Object using `CGridView`. I want to be able to check a checkbox and then go to the Create action of the Submission controller, where I will use the id of the selected row. I read that I can use the  `$.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked` function but it isn't working. The error that is displayed by Firebug is

```
TypeError: settings is undefined
...s).children('tbody').children('tr').children('td').children('input[name="' + col...
```

This is my view:

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
   'id'=>'Object', // the containerID for getChecked
   'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
   'columns'=>array(
       array(
           'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
           'id'=>'example-check-boxes' // the columnID for getChecked
       ),
        array(
            'name'=>'object_name',
            'type'=>'text',
        ),
//more columns     
   ),
));
?>
<?php
   echo CHtml::ajaxLink('Next',Yii::app()->createUrl('submission/create'),
        array(
           'type'=>'POST',
           'data'=>'js:{theIds : $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("object","example-check-boxes").toString()}'
        )
   );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
'data'=>'js:{theIds : $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("object","example-check-boxes").toString()}'
```

To this:

```
'data'=>'js:{theIds : $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked("Object","example-check-boxes").toString()}'
```

You did write `object`, but the ID of the gridview is `Object`, with an capital O.

Comment: Thank you, but now I get the following error:
POST http://localhost/publications/src/web/submission/create
 
400 Bad Request
  100ms 
js_b27...25ed.js (line 304)
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost/publications/src/web/submission/create"

Comment: Most likely your URL is invalid :-)

Comment: The URL is valid, I can access it. When I expanded the error in Firebug, I also get this: The CSRF token could not be verified.